# Rails as_json not including all associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For arguments sake, lets say I have legs as my object. I'm trying to call as_json on it and include all associations - which are set up correctly as it works perfectly in the console.

This is what I have:

```
@legs.as_json(
  :include => {
    :shoes => {
      :include => {
        :left_shoe => {
          :include => {
            :shoe_lace => {:include => :sock}
          }
        }
      },
      :right_shoe => {
        :include => {
          :shoe_lace => {:include => :sock}
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

For some reason it's not including right_shoe. It just stops at left_shoe. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're wearing your right shoe? ;)

Comment: What happend if you move `right_shoe` before `left_shoe`?

Comment: Then it returns right_shoe and excludes left_shoe

Comment: You should most likely have left_shoe and right_shoe on same level. something like :include { :left_shoe => { .. }, :right_shoe => { .. }?

Comment: Yip, that's my intention. Was more clear before edit(in terms of indentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per the comments your right shoe is at the wrong level. Try this:

```
@legs.as_json(
  :include => {
    :shoes => {
      :include => {
        :left_shoe => {
          :include => {
            :shoe_lace => {:include => :sock}
          }
        },
        :right_shoe => {
          :include => {
            :shoe_lace => {:include => :sock}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try this gem, this is pretty cool to manipulate JSON model association:

https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api